# Making images hover on mouse hover, and also showing a caption on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn and implement html/css on my website, and I just can't figure out how to setup the code to make images enlarge on hover.

I found a random snippit of code that worked, but then having text show up on hover broke it.

I'm not asking for the code to be written for me, but I'd really appreciate being pointed the right direction to set these up.

My first priority is getting the captions to show up on hover, and having the divs align in center.

I'm not sure what classes/methods/ids to implement my idea.

thank you!

Comment: If you need to be pointed in the right direction we do need to see some code.

Comment: What divs? What captions? Where's the code? Have you searched SO? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=enlarge+images+on+hover

Comment: You should place each image and its caption inside a wrapper. An then you use `caption{display:none} wrapper:hover>caption{display:block}`